# Insert and update in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update and add information in a single query.

**competitor**-table

```
  ID   Name    Age      DiveNr         Difficulty
|----|-------|----|------------------|-----------|
| 1  | Test  | 22 | 000110,011111    | 3,5       |
|____|_______|____|__________________|___________|
```

Currently I've been trying to use

```sql
INSERT INTO `competitor`(`ID`, `Name`, `Age`, `DiveNr`, `Difficulty`) 
VALUES(@idSql,@NameSql,@AgeSql,@DiveNrSql,@DiffSql)
```

But quickly realized that this was impossible.

What I want is to be able to add more items to `DiveNr` and `Difficulty` to a specific ID:

```
  ID   Name    Age      DiveNr             Difficulty
|----|-------|----|----------------------|-----------|
| 1  | Test  | 22 | 000110,011111,230400 | 3,5,6     |
|____|_______|____|______________________|___________|
```

Something like this?

```sql
SELECT ID FROM competitor WHERE ID=1;
INSERT INTO competitor(DiveNr,Difficulty)VALUES(@DiveNrSql,@DiffSql)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing lists of ids in a comma-delimited list is not the SQLish way of storing data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff indeed it is not, but it is the way of c# :)

Comment: In my book, what you want is updating a record.Why are you trying to insert?

Comment: **Normalize your database**. Instead of storing lists in a table row, add another table with foreign key constraints.

Comment: @Pikoh as you can see in the 2nd table-sketch, i want to add more information to DiveNr and Difficulty

Comment: Insert is adding a NEW record.Operations regarding modifying data in a row (it be adding or whaterver) is UPDATING a record.Anyway,as other have told you,you should normalize yout database

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I get what you are saying but i will not able to do that. I just need a query that inserts information to a cell depending on the ID

Comment: @Pikoh I am aware of that (wrote it in the question). However, i have to be able to insert information depending on what key i'm selecting.

Comment: Well then, update the datarow using DiveNr+"," +newnumber. If you don't want to normalize the database,that's the only way

Comment: @Joel Not sure why you are *"not able to"* but if you want this to work reliable you would have to use a stored procedure to add this kind of data. If you fetch the current value, modify it and write it back, you can't assure that nothing happened in the meantime because it wouldn't be an atomic operation. You could theoretically lock it but it seems like you are unnecessarily working around a problem that was caused by bad design. *"I just need a query that ..."* sounds like fixing symptoms, not problems.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the reason why i cannot do it like that, is because the file-structure of a swimming-competition depends on this numerical structure. in other words, a comma-separated list. This is generated from c# Dictionaries as well as several lists that i have no access to.

Comment: @Joel So you rather work with per-fabricated lists instead of generating them on-demand? I really don't see the logic in that. Is a **different** application accessing the database directly or is yours the only one?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer The c#-files internal structure and how they store data is not up to me to change, i'm in charge of setting the sql up right now. Pretty much, i want to add information based on what key is selected, are you telling me that this is impossible?

Comment: @Joel It's not impossible but it's really bad design that will eventually fail miserably. About your *"c#-files internal structure"*: Are you sure it's the same? Storing lists of integers as a delimited string **within** your program sounds like an even worse idea. Are you sure that's how it's done? If it is: Tell whoever is responsible for that, that some guy on the internet who sounds like he might know what he is on about (aka me) told you it's a bad idea.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer is absolutely right, but if you don't care about the problems this could cause and the bad design, i told you several coments ago what to do. Just update the row concatenating the previous value with the new

Comment: @Pikoh yeah i've solved it with that solution, but i was just hoping that there was another option out there for me.

Comment: @Joel Sorry, you lost me there ... you said *"I'm in charge of setting the SQL up right now"*. Why would you `alter` instead of just `create`-ing it from scratch? *"because i can use WHERE statements with alter table right?"* Not in any DBMS I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first get old values of that columns :-

```
declare @oldDiveNrSql varchar(100)
declare @oldDiffSql varchar(100)

set @oldDiveNrSql = (select DiveNr from competitor where ID=@idSql)
set @oldDiffSql = (select Difficulty from competitor where ID=@idSql)
```

then add old values with new values:-

```
declare @newDiveNrSql varchar(100)
declare @newDiffSql varchar(100)

set @newDiveNrSql =@oldDiveNrSql+','+@DiveNrSql
set @newDiffSql =@oldDiffSql','+@DiffSql
```

Finaly update your row with new values :-

```
update competitor set DiveNr=@newDiveNrSql,Difficulty=@newDiffSql
where ID=@idSql
```